# Check input string date format

Tags: python, pandas

I have an date `2/1/2018` ,which I am fetching from excel sheet column.

I want to check what is the actual date format of this string.

I am doing as follows:

```
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(v, '%d/%m/%Y')
    print ('date format is correct')
except :
    print ("Incorrect data format, should be mm/dd/yyyy")
```

It's printing `date format is correct`. 
For `%m/%d/%Y` this also it's saying `date format is correct`.

Actually I have two dates in excel column `2/1/2018` and `2/13/2018` and trying to convert in `%Y-%m-%d` using 
`pandas.to_datetime(value,dayfirst=True,errors='coerce').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").replace('NaT', '')`

If I remove `dayfirst=True` then it is working fine only for this excel, for other it is wrong.

as one is getting converted in `2018-01-02` and another `2018-02-13`.
How do i identify what is the actual date format ?

Comment: if `v=2/1/2018` your code should work properly

Comment: @user1767754, but how will we find `2` is day or month actually?

Comment: You will always run in this ambiguity, it's easy to distinguish when you go beyond `12`. Anyhow, you will need to have a clear format string, otherwise you will get mixups.

Comment: If that is the case why for some of the values it's working fine even though it less than `12`. Obviously it would be looking for something and then creating?

Comment: You can specify the format of the date within to_datetime function: check doc: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: here is the solution: pd.to_datetime(df['dttime'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: 2/1/2018 converted to  2018-02-01and 2/13/2018 converted to   2018-02-13

Comment: @min2bro, it's not mandatory that every time input date format is same.

Comment: if the format is not known then what exactly you wanted to check here? Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: it more of data standardization issue, you may need to get all the dates in the same format or convert.

Answer (score 1):

> If I remove `dayfirst=True` then it is working fine only for this
>   excel, for other it is wrong.

Well, yes, that's **exactly** what you should expect. If you don't specify `dayfirst=True`, you are letting Pandas use its own logic, which may be to give priority to one format over another without any assumptions regarding consistency.

**If you know your format in advance**

You should help Pandas by specifying the format of your date explicitly. This will also have performance benefits. For example:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')\
                   .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').fillna('')
```

**If you don't know your format in advance**

Trying to do this via `try` / `except` on a single date won't work. How, in isolation, can any function know whether `2/1/2018` is 1st February or 2nd January? You need to **specify explicitly** a logical order of formats to check sequentially before going any further.

Comment: True that. it's more of data standardization issue, you may need to get all the dates in the same format or convert